# Is there a way to make Maven build 1.5 and 1.6 bytecode jars simultaneously?

Tags: java, maven-2

Is there a way to make maven build 1.5 and 1.6 bytecode jars simultaneously. I know I can use classifiers to name them, but this forces to me to build them separately. I would ultimately like to do the following:

```
mvn clean install
```

And in my target directory see something like:

```
fooSource.jar
foo-1.6.jar
foo-1.5.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make maven build 1.5 and 1.6 bytecode jars simultaneously?

No, you'll have to run two clean builds. I'd use profiles and a CI engine supporting build matrix for this ([Hudson does](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/07/hudson_1122_and.html)).

Comment: +1 for keeping things separate and (if I could) +1 for hudson. Maven's build transparency could be kindly described as "murky" - forcing together what should be separate will only muddy the waters still futher.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using sub-projects ([modules](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)) with different [compiler configurations](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).

But except for installing the repository, this wouldn't be useful. Instead you can use [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in order to generate different artifacts in different cases.

Comment: I currently am using profiles, but I still have to build each one separately. In other words I have to activate one profile, then the other. If they are simultaneously active they stomp over each other.

Comment: Also consider how other people will be able to pick these up from a maven repository.  As you've done things, they won't be easily distinguishable.